# Continue Handler in mysql

Tags: mysql

Can anyone please clarify this?
Is continue handler to be used only for cursors?Or else can it be used to loop over a result set or some other table.Please help m.Thank u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general handler is statement specifies a handler that deals with one or more conditions, used with the cursors to loop among the results retrieved by the select statement in stored procedures

it will specify that whether the next iteration to be place or not

you can find more details [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-handler.html)